# How to add my existing LXD containers from differnt host to OpenStack?

Tags: 16.04, juju, openstack, cloud, lxd

I'm looking for creating a Private cloud(OpenStack) using 5 i5 pc's running windows with Ubuntu 16.04 in Oracle VM. I have setup 10 LXD containers in each of them, now I need to add all of containers to OpenStack for maintaining. What is the best method for doing it?

Thanks in advance!!